# SLF4J with Log4j is not logging in console with wildfly

Tags: java, logging, log4j, wildfly, slf4j

I am trying to use SLF4J with Log4j in my web application . I am able to log in a file , but for some reason in am not able to log in the console.

I have done the following to make it work.

I have add the libs that are neccesary to work in the WEB-INF folder.

I have create the log4j.properties as you can see in the photo.

And I the class that I have tested I add the lines to log the events.

I also add the file jboss-deployment-structure.xml in the folder META-INF because searching about the problem I see that wildfly adds slf4j as a default logging dependency. But it doesn't seems to works

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jboss-deployment-structure>
  <deployment>
    <exclusions>
      <module name="org.apache.commons.logging" />
      <module name="org.apache.log4j" />
      <module name="org.jboss.logging" />
      <module name="org.jboss.logging.jul-to-slf4j-stub" />
      <module name="org.jboss.logmanager" />
      <module name="org.jboss.logmanager.log4j" />
      <module name="org.slf4j" />
      <module name="org.slf4j.impl" />
    </exclusions>
  </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

[image]

TEMP to beosign

which line should I remove/change in the file.

This one :

```
        <console-handler name="CONSOLE">
            <level name="INFO"/>
            <formatter>
                <named-formatter name="COLOR-PATTERN"/>
            </formatter>
        </console-handler>
```

or this one ?

```
        <root-logger>
            <level name="INFO"/>
            <handlers>
                <handler name="CONSOLE"/>
                <handler name="FILE"/>
            </handlers>
        </root-logger>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think on line 6 of property file, it should be C.Target instead of stdout. Target

Comment: In the standalone.xml, are you sure you have removed the threshold filter of the CONSOLE handler? By default, there is a `<level name="INFO">` which prevents from logging anything to CONSOLE with a level of DEBUG or finer

Comment: No i dind't know about that ,@beosign could you specify which line I have to remove ? There is two level name="INFO" in mi standalone file.

Comment: Do you see something like `08:46:06,985 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1) 08:46:06.985 [default task-1] INFO  org.jboss.example.servlet - This is a test log message` on the console?